# Compiling “uinput” with polonius

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am working on a project that is split between 2 crates within a workspace. Crate A requires the polonius flag to compile. Crate B won't compile when I add the polonius flag (but compiles fine in stable and nightly). Specifically crate B seems to freeze when compiling the uinput crate (which is not a direct dependency for my code, but rather from another public crate). With polonius CPU goes to 100% and memory to 50%, and never finishes (normally compilation takes ~1m, I let it run for ~1h).

Any suggestions? Is it possible to pass a compilation flag only for a specific crate?

Comment: You might be able to do something with the `build.rs` file.